# Conditions based on Stage (dev, qual, prod)

Tags: python, development-environment, production-environment

In my context the systems have a stage. A system can be a production system, a system for quality assurance or a development system.

I know that conditions based on the stage should be avoided and in tests mocking should be used to change things. For example third party systems are not available during unittesting and mocking should be used to fake the existence of third party systems.

But sometimes I have conditions like this:

```
if settings.STAGE == constants.STAGE_DEV:
    ....
```

Up to now `constants` is from our legacy library.

I would like to use as much open source solutions as possible and avoid coding fundamental things ourselves.

Is there a better way than using above homegrown solution?

Martijn Pieters said:

> That's because there is no one-size-fits-all configuration solution either. And there never will be.

This makes me feel sad. I still have the hope that there will be a "lowest common denominator" in the future.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly and thus not sure if this helps. But if you just want to have a place that contains a hint on the environment you are in (DEV/TST/PRD/...) - I often saw that clients made an environment variable available that stored this information.

Comment: @ingofreyer is there a standard naming convention for the environment variables?

Comment: None that I found so far - sorry

Comment: The deployment mode is *just configuration*, a grouping of standard configuration settings. There is no one-size-fits-all solution, and it's really just a big switch that your existing config solution can handle.

Comment: @MartijnPieters about "one-size-fits-all solution". Yes, you are right. This does not exist yet. Up to now there is no well-known default way for this.

Comment: That's because there is no one-size-fits-all configuration solution either. And there never will be. Flask uses an environment variable, then if set to `development`, sets defaults for other configuration options. But their config infra differs materially from the Django config infra. Then there are the legion of applications that have no concept of production vs development vs staging, etc, but can reuse the same config infrastructure as apps that *do*. Then there are multi-tier staging configurations (proxy, CDN, app server, database, backend processes, etc). This is not a simple landscape!

Comment: You say "That's because there is no one-size-fits-all configuration solution either. And there never will be." Do you think the same (there will never be a) "lowest common denominator."?

Answer (score 1):

I would argue you should consider changing track a bit. While the concept of an environment (I usually call this ENV by the way) is common  and useful in deployment scripts, start scripts, Dockerfiles and whatnot, having them in the application code is bound to cause trouble.

A better solution is to have your start script know about the environments and configure (or toggle) specific features.

E.g.,

```
if settings.smtp_configured:
    send_email()
```

Then in your start script, toggle the features. Sometimes it may be useful to perform this logic in a settings.py file, but I prefer not, since I would then have to modify it every time an environment changes. It all depends on how your application gets deployed.

Comment: Yep, for example running tests is going to be nightmare; because you (OP) have test environment as well right? So whenever you have `if env == prod` its going to be skipped because of current env being test one.